# 2 xcopy commands...one works, the other fails

Tags: windows, xcopy

I have 2 xcopy commands that are virtually identical in that they both contain the same number of paramenters.  Only the paths are different.  Yet one works and the other fails and produces "Invalid number of parameters".
Here's the one that works:

```
xcopy /S /I /R /Y C:\Users\User\Desktop\Start_Menu_Backup\Database %LOCALAPPDATA%\TileDataLayer\Database
```

Here's the one that fails:

```
xcopy /S /I /R /Y C:\Users\User\Desktop\Start_Menu_Backup\icons %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one of the directories contains a space, you need to enclose it in quote marks:

```
xcopy /S /I /R /Y C:\Users\User\Desktop\Start_Menu_Backup\icons "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
```

Comment: Fahad Sadah, you are my new god.  I never knew that about spaces.  I can't thank you enough.  :)

Comment: You're very welcome :)

To avoid having to think about it, it's okay to enclose any/every parameter in "s to ensure that it's read as only one

Comment: @BillDawson: It's also a good idea to always quote arguments that contain variables, since you don't necessarily know whether they will contain spaces (or other characters that are problematic).

Comment: Good advice, Fahad & Joey.  Thanks a pantload.  :)